# How to create an external snapshot with virsh snapshot-create-as...?

Tags: qemu, snapshot, kvm, libvirt, opennebula

When I try to create a snapshot with

```
virsh snapshot-create-as one-217 snap_base "desc" --diskspec vda,file=/var/lib/one/datastores/1/2aae91bd6c04fa2db0849bc0db1342ba --disk-only --atomic
```

There is an error occurred.

error: unsupported configuration: external snapshot file for disk vda already exists and is not a block device: /var/lib/one/datastores/1/2aae91bd6c04fa2db0849bc0db1342ba

Then I run

```
virsh snapshot-list one-217
```

There is no snapshot displayed for one-217.

I run

```
virsh domblklist one-217
```

Result like this 
vda        /var/lib/one//datastores/0/217/disk.0
hda        /var/lib/one//datastores/0/217/disk.1

I am confused. How can I create an external snapshot with **virsh snapshot-create-as** command or I should try another way? And how to create a multi disk snapshot?

virsh version is
Compiled against library: libvirt 0.10.2
Using library: libvirt 0.10.2
Using API: QEMU 0.10.2
Running hypervisor: QEMU 0.12.1

Could anyone help me please? Thx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the file `2aae91bd6c04fa2db0849bc0db1342ba` already exists, so the error message you see is valid -- libvirt was rightly refusing to use an existing file, because that can cause data loss. Here's the relevant [bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=767104), which is fixed in [upstream libvirt](https://www.redhat.com/archives/libvir-list/2012-January/msg00291.html).

To resolve that, try providing path to a file that does *not* exist: `/var/lib/libvirt/images/snap1-one-217.qcow2` (or something like that).

And, judging from the error, your libvirt version seems to be old. Please use a relatively newer version (or at-least a version *above* libvirt-0.9.10).

Comment: Many thanks. The test environment is centos6.4. I upgraded libvirt with latest version(0.10.2) on centos6.4. Now I get another error . Operation not supported: live disk snapshot not supported with this QEMU binary. I am not clear this virsh command depend on what environment.